# Sonatype Nexus IQ IntelliJ is not displaying Component Info View

Tags: intellij-idea, sonatype

I am using the Sonatype Nexus IQ plugin with Intellij and trying to see the vulnerability. I configured the plugin as per https://help.sonatype.com/iqserver/integrations/iq-server-and-ides/iq-for-idea.When I select my application then it scans all dependencies and shows all components. However to see details when double click on any components then component detail does not load in
Component Info View. No error is reported in logs as well.
I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.2 (Community Edition) and Nexus IQ plugin 4.7.2-0.
Any idea what I am missing?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's my 2 cents:
I fixed the same issue by selecting no proxy in settings - appearance&Behaviour - system settings - http proxy - no proxy

p.s. make sure you only load one app at a time and make sure you check your password - if it has been changed, the components will still load but you won't see the details

Hope this helps